# Typed array of options in Props interface

Tags: typescript, astrojs

Im attempting to setup options as props for styling a button component in Astro. Fairly new to type-script. I have the following error `Generic type 'Props<style>' requires 1 type argument(s).` Here is the code:

```
---
import type { HTMLAttributes } from 'astro/types';
type styles = 'primary' | 'secondary';
export interface Props <style extends styles>extends HTMLAttributes<'a'>{
    options: style[]
    link:boolean,
    href: string,
    alt: string,
    icon: boolean,
    text?: string,
}

const {options, link, icon, text,  ...attrs } = Astro.props as Props
---
link ? <a {...attrs} class:list={['ml-auto h-[44px] sm:h-auto px-4 py-2 rounded-sm uppercase tracking-wider border-2 border-inherit',{'dark:bg-purple-50 bg-purple-800': options === "primary"}]}>{text}</a> :
<button class:list={['ml-auto h-[44px] sm:h-auto px-4 py-2 rounded-sm uppercase tracking-wider border-2 border-inherit',options==='secondary']}>{text}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Astro doesn’t currently support using generic types for `Props`.

In your case, you may be able to write the `styles` type inline inside `Props`:

```
---
import type { HTMLAttributes } from 'astro/types';

export interface Props extends HTMLAttributes<'a'> {
  options: ('primary' | 'secondary')[];
  // other props
}

const { options, ...others } = Astro.props;
//      ?^ Array<'primary' | 'secondary'>
---
```

(I’ve omitted the `as Props` assertion as if you’re using Astro’s official language tools, for example via the [VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=astro-build.astro-vscode), this is not required.)

Answer (score -1):

You are obviously missing type arguments, it literally says so

```
interface Props <style> {
    options: style[]
}
let x: Props
//     !^ Generic type 'Props<style>' requires 1 type argument(s).(2314)

let y: Props<any>
// ok
```